# Use Azure CosmosDB with MSAL Login in Single-Page-Application with CosmusDBClient

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c

I´m trying to connect to an Azure CosmosDB with my Azure AD credentials from a Single-Page-Application.

- I have a SPA with a working login. So my users are logged in!
- In Azure I have a working App-Registration with the scope "Azure Cosmos DB"."user_impersonation"
- In CosmosDB I have a Role that gives an AD group read/write access to the specific DB

I think that should work. But I´m not able to create the CosmosDB client in JavaScript.

```
const cosmosClient = new CosmosClient({
        "https://my-service.my-ressource.azure.com:443",
        // here I need an to set my credentials somewhere here. I have a valid JWT but this is not working.
       // key: myJwtAccessToken, // not working!
       // aadCredentials: new InteractiveBrowserCredential() // not working!
    });
```

I have absolutly no idea how to get that working :(

Without a key the cosmosClient instance is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> Connect to an Azure CosmosDB with my Azure AD credentials from a Single-Page-Application.

**Below are the steps I followed:**

- The modules from the `@azure/cosmos` and `@azure/identity` packages are imported using import statements.
- A **ClientSecretCredential** is used to authenticate with `Azure`, and **CosmosClient** is used to communicate with Azure `Cosmos DB`.
- An instance of **ClientSecretCredential** is created which is used to get an access token for Azure AD authentication. It requires the tenant ID, client ID, and client secret for authentication.
- Create an instance of `CosmosClient` and pass the endpoint and the `AADCredentials` to authenticate the client with Azure Cosmos DB.
- The provided database and container are accessed inside the **Try** block using the `database` and `container` objects.
- The container is used to carry certain actions, specifically reading all items using `container.items.readAll().fetchAll()`. It logs the retrieved items to the console.
- Use `az cosmosdb sql role assignment create -a <cosmosdbname> -g <rgname> -s "/" -p <service_principal_ID> -d 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002`this command to assign role to application under cosmos DB account.

```js
import { CosmosClient } from "@azure/cosmos";
import { ClientSecretCredential } from "@azure/identity";

// Azure Cosmos DB and Azure AD application configuration
const endpoint = "*****";
const tenantId = "*****";
const clientId = "*****";
const clientSecret = "*****";

const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, aadCredentials: credential });

const databaseId = "newDb";
const containerId = "insertCont";

async function main() {
  try {
    const database = client.database(databaseId);
    const container = database.container(containerId);

    const { resources: items } = await container.items.readAll().fetchAll();
    console.log("Items in the container:");
    items.forEach((item) => console.log(item));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
}
main();
```

**Output:**

```js
Items in the container:
{
  id: '1',
  name: 'Item 1',
  description: 'Description for Item 1',
  _rid: 'gKQGAPaTgK4BAAAAAAAAAA==',
  _self: 'dbs/gKQGAA==/colls/gKQGAPaTgK4=/docs/gKQGAPaTgK4BAAAAAAAAAA==/',
  _etag: '"7a02bca3-0000-0700-0000-650e89be0000"',
  _attachments: 'attachments/',
  _ts: 1695451582
}
{
  id: '2',
  name: 'Item 2',
  description: 'Description for Item 2',
  _rid: 'gKQGAPaTgK4CAAAAAAAAAA==',
  _self: 'dbs/gKQGAA==/colls/gKQGAPaTgK4=/docs/gKQGAPaTgK4CAAAAAAAAAA==/',
  _etag: '"7a029ba7-0000-0700-0000-650e89d70000"',
  _attachments: 'attachments/',
  _ts: 1695451607
}
```